# How to properly create a singleton object and use it in C++?

Tags: c++, singleton

### Background

Most of my experience with OOP comes from `Objective-C`. In that language there's a clear distinction between *instance* and *class* methods. As a result it is fairly easy to work with a singleton without any side effects.

In `C++` I haven't been that lucky and I can't seem to avoid objects being created out of my control.

### Code

I have the following object

```
class Window
{
private:
    Window();
    Window(Window const &windowCopy);
    void operator=(Window const &windowRight);

public:
    ~Window();
    static Window getSingleton();
};
```

This is the `.h`. Most of the implementation is just me using `cout` to print messages when each method in the `.h` is being called. Except for the `getSingleton()` method.

```
Window Window::getSingleton()
{
    static Window singleton;
    return singleton;
}
```

And here's my main

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Window::getSingleton();
    Window::getSingleton();

    std::cout << "Stack is being removed" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

### Result

After running this I get the following output

```
Window created   -> 0x10c9bf0e0 // This is the static singleton
Window copied    -> 0x7fff53242bb8 <- from 0x10c9bf0e0 // What is this?
Window destroyed -> 0x7fff53242bb8 // And what is it's scope?
Window copied    -> 0x7fff53242bb0 <- from 0x10c9bf0e0
Window destroyed -> 0x7fff53242bb0
Stack is being removed
Window destroyed -> 0x10c9bf0e0
```

### Question

For some reason whenever I call my singleton method, a new object appears and the singleton gets assigned to itself. Why? And how can I change this so that there's only *one* `Window` object for the entire duration of the app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing the object **by value**

```
Window Window::getSingleton()
{
    static Window singleton;
    return singleton;
}
```

you should return it by reference (or a pointer to it) instead

```
Window& Window::getSingleton()
{
    static Window singleton;
    return singleton;
}
```

That is usually the intended behavior [of the singleton pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/1938163).

Comment: Awesome! Just goes to show I'm still getting to know this language.